# How can I output if the valuable has a data on Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

At first, I want to output just "AAA".
And then, I want to output "${registered_name} BBB",if ${registered_name} already has some value.

```
<p class="message" th:text="${registered_name}+'BBB'">AAA</p>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if condition

```
<p class="message" th:if="${registered_name} != null" th:text="${registered_name}+'BBB'"></p>
<p class="message" th:if="${registered_name} == null">AAA</p>
```

Or using a method in your object who make the null comparison

```
<p class="message" th:text="${object.getRegisteredValue()}"></p>
```

And in your object make the comparison and return the value or empty

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot

It says

Static resources can be moved to /public (or /static or /resources or  /META-INF/resources) in the classpath root. Same for  messages.properties (Spring Boot detects this automatically in the root of the classpath).
So you should create ur internationalization file as messages.properties and place in the root classpath.

Or you can also edit the default location to a more proper location by adding this entry in the application.properties file

```
    #messages
   registered_name=Hello world!!
```

so you can store your files in the locale folder inside resources folder, with the name `messages.properties` or in any specific language.